# What's the difference between "why do ... have" and "why do" when used in a question?

Tags: differences, questions

It's there a difference between the two forms? Or they mean pretty much the same?

Example:

> **Why do** family members **have** to look so alike?
>
> **Why do** family members look so alike?

Or maybe the difference is a very subtle one?

Comment: They have similar meanings; the first is probably being used in a jocular (perhaps rhetorical) way; not really a question at all The second is a straightforward question seeking an answer.

Comment: @BillJ good point about the rhetorical nature of the first one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with _why_, but with the use of _have to_ meaning _must_. The two questions are very different, in the same way as _we work_ and _we have to work_.

Comment: *have to* = *must*:  “Why must family members look so alike?”

Comment: As others have pointed out, it's the exact same difference as that between "do X" and "have to do X" in any other circumstances. And that difference is general reference, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "Why do..." you're making a statement, based on an assumption that the thing you're asking about **is the case**.  If I say "Why are you so tall?" I am **stating** that you are very tall, and then going on to ask why.

So, the two statements here are

> 1) "Family members have to look so alike", ie "Family members have to resemble one another".
>
> 2) "Family members look alike"

The first statement is clearly not true - they are not **required** to look alike, and we could find many many instances of a brother and sister, for example, who look very different to one another.

The second statement would be taken by most people as a *generalization*, ie that the real meaning is "Family members tend to resemble one another", and more people would agree with that (though some people would say "Well, not all family members look alike.")

So, the difference is that the first question contains a faulty assumption, and the second doesn't (or at least one that is much less faulty than the first).

Comment: Does the first statement have a "complain-ish" tone? (e.g. Damn, why do families have to look so alike?) That's the difference that I initially spotted (but maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: Yes, it could be a complaint, in which case it is definitely **rhetorical** as @BillJ points out on the comments to the question.